# Find all combinations in array that create wanted result

Tags: python, set

Lets say we have array including id,chars like that:

```
[(1,'S'),(2,'P','S'),(3,'W','C'),(4,'T','C'),(5,'O','T','C'),(6,'O','S'),(7,'O'),(8,'P','O')]
```

Is there an efficient way to get all combinations that have in them all of the letters: ('S','P','C','T','O','W') ,(I don't want different orders), and their size is 1-6?

So far I created powerset of the array and iterated through the powerset to find all combination that have all the wanted letters in them.
It worked perfectly until I scaled the array (the array is in size of 500+- which means that its powerset is in size of ~2^500).

Example of a valid combination would be:

```
[(8,'P','O'),(2,'P','S'),(5,'O','T','C'),(3,'W','C')]'
(Because it has ALL of the letters in it)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the code you have at the moment?

Comment: Do you really need **all** combinations? If so, **all** supersets of a valid combination fufill the requirement and would need to be output as well. This makes the output size exponential.

Comment: Thanks for you answers guys! I am sorry about but I forgot to mention that I dont care about order (I want every possible combination at each size that matches) and the sets size should be 1-6 I am going to read your answers more deeply now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has lots of functions for dealing with stuff like this in the intertools module.

```
import itertools

start=[(1,'S'),(2,'P','S'),(3,'W','C'),(4,'T','C'),(5,'O','T','C'),(6,'O','S'),(7,'O'),(8,'P','O')]
good_values=set('S','P','C','T','O','W')

# Turn the tuples into sets so you can do subtraction
as_set=map(set, start)

# If the set is smaller when you pull some good_values out it is a set you care about
good_sets=[i for i in as_set if len(i - good_values) != len(i)]

# Now just ask Python for the permutations of these sets
itertools.permutations(good_sets)
```

Use itertools.permutations if you care about getting every possible order of the items that match. Use itertools.combinations if you care about every possible combination at each size that matches and you don't care about order. Use combinations and then permutations on each combination if you need both but it will be very computationally expensive.

Comment: looks like a short and beautiful answer, since I dont care about every possible order im going to use itertools.combinations. Is there a way to limit the combinations size to 1-6?

Comment: I have also made some changes and now each element in the list is an object (not a tuple) that his chars are located in a list (the name of the list is chars so if you want the chars list of the first element in start start[0].chars).
is there a simple way to deal with that?

Comment: I checked your answer (I changed itertools.permutations(good_sets) to itertools.combinations(good_sets,1)) 
and its not what I wanted (Its my bad I wasn't bright enough )
I want only the sets that have all of the letters in them
which means that in this case the result should output None

Comment: Then just change this part `len(i - good_values) != len(i)` to `not (i - good_values)`. It will tell you when the set is empty when you pull out all the good values.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to write a recursive function that can, as part of the combination formulation process, check if a tuple candidate provides a needed set of letters to help build a sequence containing all letters as required. This can partially increase efficiency:

```
data = [(1,'S'),(2,'P','S'),(3,'W','C'),(4,'T','C'),(5,'O','T','C'),(6,'O','S'),(7,'O'),(8,'P','O')]
req = ('S','P','C','T','O','W')
def group(d, c = []):
   _c = {i for b in c for i in b if isinstance(i, str)}
   if all(i in _c for i in req):
      yield c
   else:
      for a, *b in d:
         if not c or ((a, *b) not in c and any(i not in _c and i in req for i in b)) and len(c) + 1 < 7:
            yield from group(d, c+[(a, *b)])


result = list(group(data))
```

Output (first 22 results due to SO's post character limit):

```
[[(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (6, 'O', 'S')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (7, 'O')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (8, 'P', 'O')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (6, 'O', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (6, 'O', 'S'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (7, 'O'), (4, 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (7, 'O'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (8, 'P', 'O'), (4, 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (8, 'P', 'O'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (6, 'O', 'S')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (7, 'O')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (8, 'P', 'O')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C'), (3, 'W', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (6, 'O', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (7, 'O'), (3, 'W', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (4, 'T', 'C'), (8, 'P', 'O'), (3, 'W', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C'), (3, 'W', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (6, 'O', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (4, 'T', 'C')], [(1, 'S'), (2, 'P', 'S'), (6, 'O', 'S'), (3, 'W', 'C'), (5, 'O', 'T', 'C')]]
```

---

```
for i in result:
   _c = {a for b in i for a in b if isinstance(a, str)}
   assert all(k in _c for k in req), i

print('successful')
```

Output:

```
successful
```

Edit: obviously, running the solution on larger input samples will become more computationally expensive, however, a workaround to this can be to tailor the results to the greater context of your problem. Instead of loading the entire results of the generator into memory via `list`, you can use a loop to access each result from the generator on an as needed basis:

```
result = group(data)
for i in range(some_range):
   #do something, if a combination is needed:
   r = next(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try that

Comment: How can i limit the size of the sets to be between 1-6?

Comment: I run that on the 500 elements array and printed len(c)
it takes to much time to create all of the combinations that are in size of 5 or more.
I probably just have to give up on this approach (of getting all of the possible sets) because there are just too many , thanks for your help!

Comment: @IdoRozin Sorry for the late response! Unfortunately, this is a classical combinatorial problem (see [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)). It is certainly possible to continuously optimize a solution to gradually increase the sample size, however, after a point, the solution will fail. The benefit of an iterator, however, is that you can generate values on the fly. Please see my recent edit, as I provided a way to use the generator in the greater context of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations

data = [(1,'S'),(2,'P','S'),(3,'W','C'),(4,'T','C'),(5,'O','T','C'),(6,'O','S'),(7,'O'),(8,'P','O')]
req = ['S','P','C','T','O','W']
req.sort()

accepted = list()

for x in range(3, 9):
    for i in combinations(data, x):
        value = list(set(y for x in i for y in x if str(y).isalpha()))
        value.sort()
        if req == value:
            accepted.append(list(i))
```

- `x` represents the number of combination

  - the required condition can't be met for fewer than 3 combinations
  - max number of combinations is 8, per the number of `tuples` in `data`
- given `data` and `req`, `accepted` contains **64** combinations.

Comment: Thanks for you answers guys!
I am sorry about but I forgot to mention that I dont care about order (I want every possible combination at each size that matches)
and the sets size should be 1-6
I am going to read your answers more deeply now

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! the solution your provided works great on little arrays but unfortunately it isnt going to work on bigger array ;/ (it will be very slow)